# HTML-страницы, загруженные в WKWebView из папки Documents не загружают картинки и CSS

Tags: ios, swift

Я использую следующий код:

```
...
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
self.view.addSubview(webView!)

...

let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)

webView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: url)
```

В симуляторе всё выглядит так, как должно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот на реальном устройстве...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Веб-инспектор утверждает, что причиной сие аномалии является некая "Неизвестная ошибка".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это 100% не ошибка 404. Картинка точно на своём месте. Но WebKit загружать её отказывается

Так же предоставляю ссылку на тестовый проект, в котором воспроизводится данная проблема:
http://rgho.st/6x4jDsYPn

Интернет знаком с этой проблемой, но решения, работающего для меня, я не нашел.

Рассчитываю на Вашу помощь!

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Прикрепите пожалуйста пример проекта где воспроизводится ошибка.

Comment: `Интернет знаком с этой проблемой` - что за ошибка то?

Comment: @VAndrJ, Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @DaemonHK, Проблема заключается в том, что WKWebView не загружает файлы (Картинки, CSS, скрипты, Ajax-запросы из html-страниц), если его bundleUrl находится в папке Documents. При чём данная проблема воспроизводится только на реальных аппаратах версии IOS 11.0. Выше, в вопросе, я оставил ссылку на тестовый проект. Если Вы заинтересованы в решении, милости прошу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить переменную directoryUrl(урл на дерикторию с файлами) в код и поменять метод loadFileURL, у меня на девайсе помогло. Код:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    title = "Тестовый проект"

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")

    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
    self.view.addSubview(webView!)

    webView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        ])

    if(!fileOrFolderExist(name: "/file.html")) {
        copyBundleFile(name: "example", extention: "html", toFile: "/file.html")
    }
    if(!fileOrFolderExist(name: "/image.png")) {
        copyBundleFile(name: "image", extention: "png", toFile: "/image.png")
    }

    print("The path is \(applicationPath)")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: applicationPath + "/file.html")

    let directoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: applicationPath, isDirectory: true)// урл на директорию

    webView?.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: directoryUrl)

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: Как я Вам благодарен! Все действительно работает! Спасибо!